# Where should I commit a transaction -- in the Stored Procedure or in the calling application code?

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, transactions

I'm using PHP + Oracle and was wondering if there are any recommendations on where to commit my transactions.  I call stored procedures to do all my inserts/updates/deletes, and currently am committing at the end of my stored procedures.

I was wondering:

1. Is there any difference between
   calling commit/rollback in my stored
   procedure vs calling oci_commit /
   oci_rollback in my PHP code based on
   the success of the stored procedure
   call.
2. Which is preferable?  Originally
   I was thinking in the stored
   procedures themselves, but now I'm
   wondering, if there's no difference,
   perhaps it would give me more
   flexibility to commit in the calling
   application code since I could call
   several stored procedures in a
   single transaction rather than
   having to write new stored
   procedures every time I want to
   mix/match a variety of SQL
   statements in a single transaction.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I definitely agree with option 2, for the reasons you give.  Having each stored procedure act as a separate transaction can be too limiting sometimes.  Tom Kyte would back option 2 as well: see [this AskTom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:362818006460) for example.

Comment: Thanks for the link... it was spot on.

Answer (score 4):

Option 2 is the way to go as a general rule.  If you have your commits inside your stored procedures, you are making a decision that no matter who calls me, I know better and should commit any open transactions when I finish my work.

Say you have some process that has multiple steps and needs to either commit them all or roll them all back.  If that process happens to call one of your stored procedures that has a commit in it as part of doing its work, then everything up to that point could be committed by that stored procedure.

It is almost always preferable to let the caller decide about what should happen with the transaction.  One normal exception is an autonomous transaction inside a procedure for cases that need it specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about PHP/Oracle but our SQL procs check to see if they're already in a transaction.  If they are they just do what they do.  If not they create a transaction and commit/rollback themselves.  This gives us flexibility, especially for procs that are called from multiple different processes.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I'd like to see the detection mechanism.  Do you have a link?

Comment: We're just using SQL Server's built in @@TRANCOUNT

Answer (score 0):

Create a transaction with your dbConnection in controller. Execute one or more Store procedure(s) under the same transaction and connection. Do not use commit/rollback in SPs and simply throw exception. And finally use commit with Transaction you created initially in try block and rollback in catch block in controller. Rgds,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).